# Change TextView in other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-fragmentactivity, settext

I would like to change the TextView in an Fragment from my MainActivity. As the MainActivity contains a NavigationDrawer I have to change the TextView without such things like startActivityForResult.

I've also tried the LayoutInflater method, but it changes the whole layout, instead of just a small TextView.

**Edit:**

MainActivity:

```
new FRAGMENT_Main().setBalance(credits);
```

Fragment_Main:

```
public void setBalance(String credits)
{
    AmountCredits.setText(credits);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried the getSupportFragmentManager() to inflate the fragment view and target your textview ?

Comment: Hello, could you maybe post some code sample?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you add fragment to your activity?

Answer (score 0):

**If i get your question**
If the MainActivity has the Instance of that fragment.

Just make a function in Fragment to update the `textview`.
and call it from **MainActivity** using the `fragment's instance`.

Comment: Hello, I've edited the question, do mean it like this or could you send the code please?

Comment: @Tester3 how u r adding the fragment.. in XML or using fragment manager ?

Comment: I am adding it with fragment Manager

Comment: @Tester3 when adding it using fragment manager, you have created an instance ... or show or your code... let me explain..